# Incorrect Context bpy.ops.paint.image_paint(mode='NORMAL', stroke=None)

Tags: python, texture-painting

can somebody help me figuring out what the correct context of the `image_paint operator` is?

I thought it needed to be the VIEW_3D Area with `region_type` set to WINDOW but I always get a runtime error.

This is the operator I am trying to run (with strokes instead of "None")

`bpy.ops.paint.image_paint(mode='NORMAL', stroke=None)`

```
import bpy

def get_override(area_type, region_type):
     for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
         if area.type == area_type:             
            for region in area.regions:                 
                if region.type == region_type:                    
                    override = {'area': area, 'region': region} 
                    return override
    #error message if the area or region wasn't found
    raise RuntimeError("Wasn't able to find", region_type," in area ", area_type,
                        "\n Make sure it's open while executing script.")

override = get_override( 'VIEW_3D', 'WINDOW' )

start = bpy.context.scene.frame_start
end = bpy.context.scene.frame_end

bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.image_paint.use_clone_layer = True
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.image_paint.mode = 'IMAGE'

bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(override, type = 'CAMERA')        
bpy.ops.paint.texture_paint_toggle()

for i in range(start,end):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_current = i
        bpy.ops.paint.brush_select(override, paint_mode='ACTIVE', texture_paint_tool='CLONE')
        override = get_override( 'VIEW_3D', 'WINDOW' )
        bpy.ops.paint.image_paint(mode='NORMAL', stroke=None)
        i = i + 1

bpy.ops.paint.texture_paint_toggle()
```

Above is the code I was trying to run. A mesh object needs to be selected and a camera needs to be in the scene.

Comment: i think space_data and or region_data may be the other key in your context override dictionary that you need.

Comment: John did You solve the problem?
I am trying to image_paint also in newest version of blender but always getting wrong context Runtime error.

Comment: Ditto! Did anyone solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`bpy.ops.paint.image_paint` can operate in two different editors (space_types / area.type): The Image Editor and the 3d Viewport. Therefore the required context depends on whether you want to paint directly to the image texture through the image editor or the 3d viewport. The image editor will operate with 2D pixel coordinates and the 3d editor 3D coordinates.

**Image Editor Poll conditions:**

bpy.context.mode = 'PAINT_TEXTURE',
area.type = `IMAGE_EDITOR`,
region.type = `WINDOW`

**3D Editor Poll Conditions:**

bpy.context.mode = 'PAINT_TEXTURE' ,
area.type = `VIEW_3D`,
region.type = `WINDOW`,
Active tool must be a brush

Note that in paint mode the tool is assumed to be a brush in code and doesn't do a tool check. This should bone to future proof any code.

The intention of the code in question is to paint to the 3d Viewport. Therefore the context used is correct. This issue is that the `override` isn't passed to operator call. It should be:

```
bpy.ops.paint.image_paint(override, mode='NORMAL', stroke=stroke_elements)
```

As pointed out, stroke cannot be None, so stroke_elements would be a valid collection of OperatorStrokeElement

The bpy.ops.paint.brush_select ops parameters have changed since the question. As of 2.92 the correct use in this instance would be

```
bpy.ops.paint.brush_select(override, image_tool='CLONE')
```